# dygraphs doesn't show the line for more than 10,000 datapoints

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am trying to plot a graph using dygraph function for a dataset with more than 100,000 datapoints. As soon as I try it the graph appears empty. I tried to shorten the dataset and it turns out that dygraph shows graph for dataset up to 10,000 entries only. Here is a sample with 9,999 datapoints

```
dygraph(ts(1:9999))
```

[up to 9999 datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObtGp.png)

as soon as I change to 10,000 it doesn't show anything

```
dygraph(ts(1:10000))
```

[10000 datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTxeb.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Feels like this could be a bug in the dygraph code, but I can't say for certain. Did some digging directly in the dygraph source code but couldn't find the cause.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! Agree, apparently this is a bug. Nevertheless I found a solution to this. If you convert your data to time series using timeSeries function, it starts working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I came to conclusion that this is a bug. Nevertheless I found a solution to this. If you convert your data to time series using timeSeries function, it starts working.

For example:

```
y = timeSeries(1:1000000, 1:1000000)
dygraph(y)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Could you post the code that you used to fix the issue?

Comment: yeah sure! I did it this way:
`y = timeSeries(1:1000000, 1:1000000)`
`dygraph(y)`